# Android emulator storage gets filled progressively every time i use it

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

The android emulator storage gets filled progressively every time I use it. I keep having to wipe clean the emulator after its storage gets filled up every few times. How do I fix this? I keep having to re-login into my google account and install the other apps I need to test multiple times.

The bulk of the size seems to be from `userdata-qemu.img` and `userdata-qemu.img.qcow2`

I tried copying these files the first time and overwriting them once they get too big, but that seems to completely mess up the emulated device, and I had to delete it and make a new one
[image]